# Google Cloud - Compute Engine Cant connect with ssh & serial console works after reboot

Tags: linux-kernel, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Recently in my Google Cloud Compute Engine I have some issues with the ssh & serial console. My VM seems to "crash" about a certain time, all the programs running in this machine are not responding (docker).

I tried to reset the vm & changing os but the problem persist here is Putty Error screenshot: 
[image]

I tried to connect to the machine via the serial option but it I can't login,it blocks at the login prompt. I tried many times but when i reboot the vm, it works perfectly.

**EDIT :** 
Here is the list of the installed programs : 
 - Docker
 - Docker-Compose
 **Docker images : **

```
* Neo4j<br/>
* A C# program<br/>
* nginx<br/>
* CachetHQ<br/>
* PostgreSQL<br/>
* CertBot<br/>
```

** My machine : **
Custom, 2vCpu and 5go of memory
Here is the output of cat /proc/meminfo : 
https://hastebin.com/qenowepira.http
I'm about to try to disable CachetHQ & PostgreSQL

Comment: Could you give use more details? What is currently installed on the VM, did you manage to connect before? Did you do any updates?

Comment: I had a similar issue before where one of the programs on boot-up was using all the available memory on the machine, so ssh didn't connect. A quick boot fixed the problem until the program consumed all memory again. Try `cat /proc/meminfo` upon reboot and looking at MemFree if that's an issue.

Comment: Adding to @rohanphadte suggestion, you may add more memory by [changing the machine type](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance).